# Gulp executes but does nothing

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to run some gulp task when my server initiates. The gulp tasks seem to execute, but they do nothing.
In my server.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

self.gulpRun = function(){
    require('./tauler/gulpfile.js');
    gulp.start('default');
};

console.log('gulp start');
self.gulpRun();
console.log('gulp end');
```

And in my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util')
    clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
   gutil.log('Gulp is running!');
   gulp.src('src')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function(){
    gutil.log('Gulp-clean is running!');
    gulp.src('public').pipe(clean());
});
```

Output:

```
gulp start
[20:32:33] Gulp-clean is running!
[20:32:33] Gulp-default is running!
gulp end
```

The rellevant filesystem (before and after the code runs) as follows:

```
/project-root
├── server.js
├── public
│   └── whatever.html
└── tauler
    ├── src
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── ...
    └── gulpfile.js
```

I've already tried different combinations within "src" and "dest" like "./public" or "path.join(__dirname,'public')".
The files and directories don't change.

Any idea on how to proceed? Thnks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do that is to call the gulp file as a child process from your server file to make sure that after the process will finish your RAM will be clear from the gulp stuff.

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;



const gulp = spawn('gulp', ["default", "--gulpfile", "./tauler/gulpfile.js"], { stdio: 'inherit' });

gulp.on('close', () => {
    console.log("gulp done");
});
```

To refer to all of the content in the src folder use

```
const gulp  = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
   gulp.src('./src/**/*.*')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: thanks! it worked partially (only the clean task) but the files are not copying from "src" to "public" and still don't understand why it was not working in the original form... =/